# AngularFire Firebase email/password authentication gives "Error: This custom Firebase server ('firebaseapp.com') does not support delegated login."

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am trying to get AngularFire user authentication with email/password functioning but am getting errors.

The error sent back from the $authWithPassword call is:

Error: This custom Firebase server ('firebaseapp.com') does not support delegated login.

You can look in the console log of the plunker below to see this message.  I cannot find any docs that say anything about needing any additional setup to support delegated login, or how I would do so.

The console log of the plunker will also show periodic web requests to the firebase app URL that result in a 404.  These start occurring as soon as the $firebaseAuth(ref) call is made.  The content of those responses is an HTML page with a title of: Site not found.

I have a demo user 'demo@zerrtech.com' with a password 'demo' and a [sample plunker set up here](http://plnkr.co/edit/59Uw5a).  Here is the code:

```
angular.module('authdemo', ['firebase'])

.controller('authCtrl', function($scope, $log, $firebaseAuth) {
  var ref = new Firebase('https://zerrtech-sandbox.firebaseapp.com');
  var auth = $firebaseAuth(ref);
  auth.$authWithPassword({
    email: 'demo@zerrtech.com',
    password: 'demo'
    }).then(function(authData) {
      $log.info("Login Successful:");
      $log.info(authData);
    }).catch(function(error) {
      $log.info("Login Failed:");
      $log.info(error);
    });
});
```

This is a pretty basic use case, and code right from the examples, so what am I missing?

Comment: Firebase databases live at `firebaseio.com`, not `firebaseapp.com`.

Comment: Ah, you are right!  Within the "Manage App" there are still some places that say firebaseapp.com, but on the main "Dashboard" it says firebaseio.com.  If you wanna add it as an answer, I'll mark it complete. Thanks.

Comment: The database lives at `firebaseio.com`. If you also use Firebase Hosting, your deployed application will live on `firebaseapp.com`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are instantiating your Firebase object with the wrong url. Firebase databases live at `firebaseio.com`. Firebase hosting sites live at `firebaseapp.com`.